# Bash: unusual line break

Tags: bash, url, line, href, break

I coded a small script in bash, which read some HTML and should print the href of a link:

```
#!/bin/bash

link=$(echo $source | sed -ne 's#^.*<a href="\([^"]*\)".*$#\1#p')

  if [ "$(echo "$link" | grep '/fonts/list/style')" ]
    then
      echo "http://www.domain.com$link/10000"
  fi
```

The var source is in my example:

```
<li><span>19</span><a href="/fonts/list/style/home words">linktext</a></li>
```

The Problem: The script print not

```
http://www.domain.com/fonts/list/style/home words/1000
```

instead of it prints

```
http://www.domain.com/fonts/list/style/home
words/1000
```

How can I remove or avoid this line break?

Comment: Don't use [tag:bash], [tag:sed], [tag:grep], ... to parse HTML. Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: Show how you're setting `$source`, that's probably where the problem is. Also, you should quote it in `echo "$source"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `"` appearing in the `<li>...`:

This worked to me:

```
#!/bin/bash

source="<li><span>19</span><a href=\"/fonts/list/style/home words\">linktext</a></li>"

link=$(echo $source | sed -ne 's#^.*<a href="\([^"]*\)".*$#\1#p')

  if [ "$(echo "$link" | grep '/fonts/list/style')" ]
    then
      echo "http://www.domain.com$link/10000"
  fi
```

Output

```
http://www.domain.com/fonts/list/style/home words/10000
```

Comment: Thanks. I simplify the code for the post a bit. If I save the link in a array, e.g. ** catlinks[$i]=$(echo "http://www.domain.com$link/10000") **, there in is a break again. Do you have a idea?

Comment: It depends on the cases. What's better is to follow [gniourf_gniourf's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238389/bash-unusual-line-break/17238493#comment24978219_17238389) and don't use bash for this.

Comment: Solved by replace the space with %20 for space. Code: link=${link// /\%20}